# Game Developing in C# related questions

Tags: c#

I've been making a game over the past week or two and I have some questions I couldn't find the answer to in forums.

1.
While using Forms as the character moves to the most right of the form how can I make it so it moves the background parallel to the character in a way that he "travels" the map. A simple example is Mario,as you play the game the map draws with objects and such.

2.I've seen some people code in a very organized way. They're using classes that they call to the main form, when using KeyUp,KeyDown,MouseUp,MouseDown,Timers is it possible to still use those while in a class?
(Theres a class called Movement and it involves these methods to put is simpley)

3.As the character kills the picturebox(enemy) I'm trying to create a new one, with the same properties and spawn it on the far right edge of the screen.
Yet as its my first time doing such a thing and with no help to be found from outside sources I just messed it up and I didn't work.

I'm calling createEnemy() as the last enemy dies

```
private void createEnemy()
    {
        PictureBox enemy = new PictureBox();
        this.Controls.Add(enemy);
        this.Controls.Add(enemyhealth);
        enemyhealth.Visible = true;
        enemy.Visible = true;
        enemy.BackColor = Color.Black;
        enemy.Size = new Size(34, 40);
        enemy.Location = new Point(character.Location.X, character.Location.Y);
        enemydamage();
        enemyhealth.Location = new Point(enemy.Location.X - 10, enemy.Location.Y - 17);
        enemyhealth.Value = 30;
        enemy.Refresh();
        enemyhealth.Refresh();
        enemy.BringToFront();
        enemyhealth.BringToFront();
    }
```

Thank you for answering.
I do not expect answers in codem,just the main idea of doing it.

Comment: In its current form your question is going to be very hard to answer. We have no idea how you have implemented your game and how your framework looks like

Comment: Three questions in one is usually a bad fit. It makes the question unanswerable. Also, you don't really have a programming problem, but a 'how to get started' question, which don't do good here either.

Comment: I am c# begginer but i think you should not create a new picturebox for every new character

Comment: @ErikŠťastný instead of creating picturebboxes, you could use a [single control (selfmade)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxys6ytf(v=vs.110).aspx) and draw the enemies as sprites by [overwriting the OnPaint event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b818z6z6(v=vs.110).aspx). You might also take a look at [XNA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/en-en/library/bb203893(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx).

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

As others have indicated it would be better to have separate questions and to try to make the questions more specific.  But let me do my best to answer.

1)  If I understand correctly, what you are trying to achieve is a scrolling background.  Quite a bit can go into achieving this well.  For performance and memory reasons you usually don't want to render or store the entire map -- ideally you don't want to show much more than you are going to display. This CAN be done with GDI in WinForms.  For example see:

- Scrolling GDI pixels in a panel control 
  [Scrolling GDI pixels in Panel control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029741/scrolling-gdi-pixels-in-panel-control)

I used to do a lot of this sort of stuff using WinG library back in the days of Windows 95.  Or you could potentially even just add scrollbars to your form--but you'll probably hit performance limits pretty quickly.

But as others have noted GDI/Winforms isn't really designed for this task.  A toolset more specifically designed for games will make your life a lot easier.  For example, XNA will provide you with a lot of tools that will make your life as a game developer easier.  Check out this article:

- Making scrolling backgrounds with XNA
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203868.aspx

2) First of all, it should be noted that in C# a Form (and almost everything else) IS a class.  If KeyPreview property on the form is set to true, the OS will make sure the form gets events like KeyPress, etc..  Otherwise, the focused controls will get this keyboard events first and may pass them on up.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171536(v=vs.110).aspx may be useful.

But you can also call a method of another class from your form's handler and thus delegate handling the event to your other class.  For example you might have your OnKeyPress method call Player.MoveRight or Player.MoveLeft depending on the value of the input.

3) Creating an enemy -- can you provide more details about what is not working here?  What result are you expecting and what is your code actually doing?  It looks like your setting your enemy's location to be the same as your player location--not the right edge of the screen--and I don't see where you set the image for your picturebox if you are expecting an image.  A more object oriented way to approach this problem might be to have a class that represents your enemy with the PictureBox as a property of that class.

If you decide to look into XNA, a Sprite would be a great way to handle both your player and enemy:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203919.aspx

Comment: As i agree with most of your answer.... XNA is long dead now. Monogame is its successor (most of the code is identical)

Comment: @yan yankelevich Thanks for the commet. As you can tell, I've been out of the game development world for a while... the drudgery of the line of business applications in adulthood.  :-)

Comment: sadly i'm in the same situation. So i guess i a few years i will have no idea about what framework/engine will be the best suited for games development (Unity i guess) :-)

Comment: Thank you for all the answers.
I am currently downloading Monogame and I look forward to use it.

3) What actually happens is as the enemy dies it spawns on the player(I chose to) a new picturebox yet the enemyhealth(progress bar) is not moving parallel to the picturebox an attribute that doesn't seem to follow after the first picturebox "dies".

Comment: I'm currently creating an RPG game using the MonoGame. is there any particular tutorial you could suggest that might set me on the right course if not thanks for all the help!

Comment: Maybe try this: http://scottlilly.com/learn-c-by-building-a-simple-rpg-index/